# Rebase two branches onto another branch

Tags: git, rebase

Given the following git history:

[image]

What would be the simplest way to rebase branches `feature/1` and `feature/2` onto `master` to achieve the following history:

[image]

So far I have come up with the following:

1. Checkout `feature/2`(head of the commit chain I want to rebase)
2. Rebase the branch onto master: `git rebase master`
3. Change the head of the `feature/1` branch: `git branch -f feature/1 <hash>`

Where `<hash>` is the hash of the duplicated `Feature 1` commit created by the `rebase` command.

It works fine but seems too complicated to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest and quickest solution is the one you've already worked out.  You can combine steps 1 and 2

```
git rebase master feature/2
```

and you might find it easier to avoid dealing with commit ID's, in cases (like your example) where it's easy to calculate an expression for the target commit

```
git branch -f feature/1 feature/2^
```

You could, as others mention, use two rebases.  However, this is not simpler.  That is to say, whether the sophistication of the commands is simpler is a matter of opinion; but what you're telling git to do is objectively more complicated.  And as a consequence of that, there is more opportunity for things to go wrong.  The specific technique of rebasing `feature/1` first, and then rebasing `feature/2` over `feature/1`, for example, relies on detection of duplicate patch ID's during the 2nd rebase, which will fail in unfortunate ways if any conflict resolution occurred during the 1st rebase.  If you really want to use a 2-rebase approach, I would recommend the 2nd rebase be done as

```
git rebase --onto feature/1 feature/1@{1} feature/2
```

as this avoids even considering re-rewriting the `feature/1` commits.  (The `feature/1@{1}` is a reflog entry that points to `feature/1` before it was rebased.)  But then you're using less-common rebase syntax, which as far as I can tell is at least as "not simple" as what you were doing in the first place.

Alternately you can use `--fork-point` to tell git to automatically interpret the reflog and try to figure out which commits would be dups.

```
git rebase --fork-point feature/1 feature/2
```

As long as you're doing both rebases at nearly the same time on the same clone, this will work *most of the time*.  But it is adding more complexity (in the form of "magic" that git does under the hood), so you'd need to understand that it can go wrong, and if it does either (a) know enough about what it tried to do to diagnose the issue, or (b) back out and use one of the other methods.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the 2-rebase approach fails where there are conflicts during the first rebase. Your second proposal works fine but is far from what I meant as "simple".
Your first proposal however doesn't work. It fails with 
`zsh: no matches found: feature/2^`

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a git error but it's a shell error. Wrapping the `feature/2^` in quotes made it work.

Comment: Also, can you explain the syntax of the `feature/1@{1}` or point me to a relevant resource?

Comment: @KubaSzymanowski - `feature/1@{1}` is a reflog expression.  It will only work in the specific repo where the first rebase occurred (reflogs are local, so other clones won't see it), and you also have to be aware that reflogs expire (but the default is to keep them for a reasonably long time).  But basically it says "looking at the history of places `feature/1` has pointed, got back one step into the past".  See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Answer (score -3):

Tell git what you're doing and the sequence is:

```
git rebase master feature/1
git rebase feature/1 feature/2
```

like so, you can c&p this:

```
git init test; cd $_
doit() { eval echo \>$*; git add $1; git commit -m "$2"; }
doit master "Initial commit"
git checkout -tb feature/1
doit file1 "Feature 1"
git checkout -tb feature/2
doit file2 "Feature 2"
git checkout master
doit master "New commit on master"
```

producing your graph exactly:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
* 35cfad5 (feature/2) Feature 2
* 46b79ae (feature/1) Feature 1
| * ae89e31 (HEAD -> master) New commit on master
|/  
* f1138eb Initial commit
$
```

and now, since you told git your branch structure,

```
$ git rebase master feature/1
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Feature 1
$ git rebase feature/1 feature/2
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Feature 2
$
```

Comment: Patterns like this, which tell git to rebase the same commits multiple times (and rely on it to "fix" the mistake with patch ID checks) are not reliable.  It's a shame people keep upvoting answers like this, because they are teaching people to use rebase in ways that work in simple cases then fail in seemingly-mysterious ways when it's most inconvenient.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger In another answer, which got deleted, you mentioned that the syntax here is `rebase <upstream> <source>`. What do you mean by `upstream`? We're not dealing here with a remote repository and unless I got something wrong `upstream` refers to said remote repository(like origin).

Comment: @KubaSzymanowski : git has an unfortunate habit of using the same word to mean similar-but-different things in different contexts. I think usage of `upstream` with rebase might derive from the use case where you're moving local changes to catch up with the remote (as in with `pull --rebase`); more generally it typically means "the branch from which 'my' changes (the changes I'm rewriting) diverged". At a technical level it means something like "while choosing commits to rewrite, exclude this and anything reachable from it, as they are upstream (topologically) of what I'm rewriting".

Comment: @KubaSzymanowski : ... that said, this is really too complex a topic to do justice in comments.  I recommend reviewing the `git rebase` docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase ; and note that when you just give two refs, the first one is `<upstream>`, and that there is a distinct `--onto` option - which is why it really doesn't work to say `onto` when meaning `upstream` in this context.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger What are you talking about? This rebases each commit exactly once.

Comment: @jthill - No, it does not.  The second cmomand says "rebase everything reachable from `feature/2` that is *no longer* reachable from `feature/1`.  But don't take my word for it - I've described the failure conditions multiple times.  Run the test.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger It does for me, and as you point out, even if you don't tell git which branches should track which other branches it usually figures out the right result anyway.

Comment: @jthill - Since you've chosen to use dishonest edits to "change" the correctness of my comments, I'm going to keep this short (and it will be my final reply on this thread). That adds a new complexity (we were asked for the *simplest* solution), especially if it wasn't anticipated when the branches were created; and it assumes that there is no need for a different tracking configuration that would conflict with what you've done.